# Building OpenCV 2.49 with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, build, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I try to build the OpenCV libraries with visual studio 2012 but I always get the following Error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "....\lib\Debug\opencv_core249d.lib".
```

I downloaded the latest code from the git repository and used Cmake 2.8.10.2 to create the projects. I also disabled the cuda support due to the cuda 5.0 and visual 2012 incompatibility.

Comment: Does the `.lib` file exists? Are you linking the right library? There are many things to consider.

Comment: No this .lib file doesn't exist. Actually I want to build this .lib and many others just as the corresponding .dll files. Therefore I don't understand why the compiler is asking for a .lib which I want to build. :/

Comment: Its asking for this lib as a dependency for the next component it is trying to build

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV 2.43 does not work well with Visual Studio 2012. So I wrote a simple tutorial.

> http://answers.opencv.org/question/6495/visual-studio-2012-and-rtlfreeheap-error/#6603

But your OpenCV edition is 2.49. I'm not sure whether this will work. You can still try it. Good luck.

Comment: I just switched back to visual studio 2010 since it causes me less problems. I think I will wait till OpenCV and Cuda will properly work on the new visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (In visual studio 2008). The problem was that I had included a ; (semicolon) between all my Additional Dependencies (opencv_core249d.lib opencv_imgproc249d.lib etc....). When I removed the semicolons it worked.