# CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH undeclared in 'How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio' sample code

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm following the instructions in [How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to) but I'm getting errors from the sample code:

- error C2065: 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH' : undeclared identifier
- error C2065: 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT' : undeclared identifier
- error C2065: 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' : undeclared identifier

I think the identifiers that are undeclared should be declared in highgui so why am I not getting them despite the demo code's `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>`?

Here are the steps I have taken.

1. I've unpacked the OpenCV (Version 2.4.6) files into `C:\OpenCV`, run `setx -m OPENCV_DIR C:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc11` from an elevated command prompt and added `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin` to my path (following instructions in [Installation in Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html)). Then using the Property pages (View -> Property Pages or Shift-F4) set to 'All Configurations'
2. I've added `$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include` to my C/C++ Additional Include Directories

[image: VS12 Property Page Screenshot]

3. I've added `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib` to the linker Additional Library Directories

[image: VS12 Property Page Screenshot]

4. I've cut-an-paste the directory listing of the lib files in `C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib` into my input Additional Dependencies

[image: VS12 Property Page Screenshot]

5. I've copied the sample code from [the article](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to) into a new C++ console app (with ATL). I had to change one line in the template code from `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` to `int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])`

I think the identifiers that are undeclared should be (are) declared in highgui so why am I not getting them despite the demo code's `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>`?

Other people having similar issues getting this sample code working in the [How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to) note seem to fall over with link errors (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14153781/575530) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14968548/575530)) but I am getting past the linker.

========== EDIT ==========

There appear to be more insurmountable difficulties with the sample code. It is documented as a simple example to load and display an image whose path is supplied as the sole argument to `main`, while the code listing itself is video code requiring four command line arguments (i.e. it first checks and stops if `argc != 5`). I've submitted a [documentation bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3315). I think the sample code listing should have been be taken from this: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/introduction/display_image/display_image.cpp

Comment: I have also asked this on the OpenCV forum, I hope that's not poor etiquette http://answers.opencv.org/question/22190/cap_prop_frame_width-undeclared-in-how-to-build/

Comment: I do not know if this might be a problem here but you use x64 binaries for x86 configuration. You have set C:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc11, note that \x64\ prefix. Edit your path to C:\OpenCV\Build\x86\vc11 if you want to run code on 32-bit architecture machines. Otherwise create new Active Solution Platform under Configuration Manager > Active Solution Platfrom > <New...> > x64

Comment: @OpenMinded you are right. Once I fixed the issue that the question is about using [morynicz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19288246/575530) I then get a link error: `error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'` which your suggestion fixes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with CV_CAP_ or cv::CAP_... It looks like there were some changes aiming to improve consistency of constants in OpenCV...

Comment: That's it, thanks @morynicz. Over on the OpenCV forum berak notes that it looks like there was some mix-up (in the tutorial) with the constants and suggests I use CV_CAP_PROP_* in 2.4.6 or cv::CAP_PROP_* in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I am using the opencv 2.4.6 and this has helped me do the trick

```
change CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH into CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
change CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT into CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
change CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT into CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
```

and similarly if there are any other cap prop keywords into cv cap prop keywords

try this.